# Extjs use class/singelton in different applications

Tags: javascript, class, extjs

How can I use a custom class with basic functions in multiple projects / applications?

I obviously do not want to copy it

```
Ext.define('util.ConfigData', {
    singleton: true,

    _debug: false,
    log: function(message) {
        if(this._debug){
            console.log(message);
        }
    }
```

});

Comment: Do you use one workspace for all functions? That would make a huge difference how to approach the problem.

Comment: This depends how you are going to build your ExtJS app. Using Sencha Cmd you can create a (libary) package and use it in every project - require this package in app.json or package.json. Or the simplest solution, concat all (common/shared) files, store as js file and load before your app / package.

Comment: @hwsw how can i create a library package? I did try to find something about it. I know how to create with cmd a concat all file, thats how we actually run our old applications.

Comment: Hi @Dinkheller, what is a workspace for you. I would like to have 2 different projects. One the application and one like a library which requires functionallity. like a app_core.js

Comment: WORKSPACE: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.4.0/guides/workspaces.html Allows you to create several apps within a workspace. The workspace holds the different ExtJS versions, which allows you to create a new app within seconds. Plus it allows you to add packages.

Comment: PACKAGES: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.4.0/guides/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html Allows you to share code to several apps in your workspace. You can build a package (same as you build an app) and share this remotely or only in your workspace apps.

Comment: So if you create a package and add your util singleton class to it, you can require it from several apps in your workspace or in external apps. A package should be the way to go.

Comment: @JensH check Dinkhellers answers, i meant a cmd-package with libary package. but you can also use a different bundler which basically should concat the files. one thing to keep in mind here, that files have to be in the right order (this is what cms does -> sorting the files using requires and concat + minify(uglify in a prod build.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Dinkheller that worked for me.

The links

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.4.0/guides/cmd_packages/cmd_creating_packages.html

and

https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.4.0/guides/cmd_packages/cmd_packages.html

are showing how do to it. Follow the description and it will work.